# what is the right way to write this code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

im pretty sure the
`tabelist.innerHTML = '<option>invalid value</option>'`

isn't the best way to make an element and insert it in another one, but how i am supposed to do this if is not this way?

```
let submit = document.querySelector('input#submit')
let tabelist = document.querySelector('select#tabe')
submit.addEventListener('click', clicar)
function clicar(){
    let tabenumber = 1
    let number = Number(document.querySelector('input#number').value)
    if(number == ''){
        tabelist.innerHTML = '<option>invalid value</option>'
    }else{
        tabelist.innerHTML = ''
        for(number*tabenumber; tabenumber <=10; tabenumber++){
            tabelist.innerHTML += `<option>${number} x ${tabenumber} = ${number*tabenumber} </option>`
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a valid way to do it.

Comment: You can create elements in JS and append them to a parent element, but I'm not convinced that makes things any clearer/easy to maintain for the sort of thing you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.innerHTML` is valid, but should only be used as a last resort because it has potential side effects of:

- wiping out event handlers that were set on elements that are now
  being replaced
- slowing down the rendering of the page because the     HTML parser
  must parse the new content
- potentially exposing a    security hole by allowing malicious script
  to execute

Another approach would be to use the Document Object Model to create, configure and inject an element:

```js
const list = document.querySelector("select");

// Create new element
const option = document.createElement("option");

// Configure new element
option.textContent = "Item 1";

// Inject into existing element
list.appendChild(option);
```

```html
<select>

</select>
```

Comment: bet bro, tysm fr i was trying to use `let opt = document.createElement("option")` and then `opt.innerHTML` instead `textContext`